# calculate mean and variance for weighted discrete random variables in R

Tags: r, weighted, weighted-average

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text="  X prob
1 1  0.1
2 2  0.2
3 3  0.4
4 4  0.3", header=TRUE)
```

Is there any built-in function or elegant way to calulate mean and variance for discrete random variables in R?

Comment: I changed the row names so they were unique, a requirement for dataframes in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `weighted.mean` function in base R and the Hmisc package has a bunch of wtd.* functions.

```
> with(dat, weighted.mean(X, prob))
[1] 2.9

require(Hmisc)
>  wtd.var(x=dat$X, weights=dat$prob)
[1] Inf
# Huh ?  On investigation the weights argument is suppsed to be replicate weights
# So it's more appropriate to use normwt=TRUE
> wtd.var(x=dat$X, weights=dat$prob, normwt=TRUE)
[1] 1.186667
```

The survey package from Thomas Lumley provides much more than this simplistic example illustrates. It has the mechanism for handling complex weighting schemes for a variety of statistical modeling procedures:

```
require(survey)
> dclus1<-svydesign(id=~1, weights=~prob, data=dat)
>   v<-svyvar(~X, dclus1)
> v
  variance     SE
X   1.1867 0.7011
```

These are sample statistics rather than the variances that would be calculated for abstract random variables. This result does seem appropriate for a statistical system, but might not be the correct answer for a probability homework question.

Comment: Why is this variance so different from `E(x^2) - E(x)^2`?

Comment: So different? It's not surprising that it is lower than `var(X)=> mean(dat$X^2) - mean(dat$X)^2 = [1] 1.25`, since the probability weights are shifted to one side of the distribution.

Comment: Please read the help page. Running with `normwt` does exactly what you suggest.

Comment: I fail to understand why the wtd.var result should be different than the result of `var(x)` which is 3.5.